# Encoding a JSONP <script src = Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, jsonp, google-books

I am attempting to access Google Books in order to an ISBN Code to get details of a book, I have a number of problem, which are:

A) I am trying to assemble a script request e.g.   with the ISBN code concatenated into the URL. I have not managed to do this successfully - and I don't know why.

B) I then want to update a div in the DOM with this generated script dynamically, such that it will then execute.

C) I am finding it a bit of a puzzle as to the format of the returned data and the argument name of the function call contained in the Google response.

Has anyone else encountered the same problem and can offer guidance re A thru C above.

I enclose JavaScript code below.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#viewbook-button').live('click', function() {
              isbnCode = this.text;

              alert("ISBN is : " + isbnCode + " " + this.text + " as well");

              alert("Getting JSONP Google Books data");

              isbnCode = "0451526538";

              JSONPstr = '<' + 'script ' + 'src="' + 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=ISBN' + isbnCode; 
              JSONPstr = JSONPstr + '&callback=handleJSONPResponse">' + '</script>';

              alert("un-Escaped JSONP string" + JSONPstr);

              escJSONPstr = escape( escJSONPstr );

              alert("Escaped JSONP string");

              //divstr = "";
              //divstr = divstr + escape(<script src=");
              //divstr = divstr + encodeURIComponent(https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=ISBN); 
              //divstr = divstr + escape(isbnCode);
              //divstr = divstr + encodeURIComponent(&callback=handleJSONPResponse);
              //divstr = divstr + escape("></);
              //divstr = divstr + escape(script);
              //divstr = divstr + escape(>);


              $('#jsonp-call').html(escJSONPstr);

              // This will cause the handleJSONPResponse function to execute when the script is dynamically loadedinto div.
              // The data wrapped in a function call will be returned from the Google Books server.
              // This will cause the handleJSONPResponse function to execute below.

            });   // end viewbook-button
        });       // end document.ready

        function handleJSONPResponse(response) {
          var tmp = response;
          alert(tmp);

        };

  </script>


  </head>

  <body> 
    <h2>Show Details of Books Ordered by a Customer</h2>
    <a href="#" id="getcusts-button">Get Customer Details</a>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="tablist">Tables will be Listed Here</div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="Google-call">The JSONP generated src= statement will go here and execute</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Problem solved - thanks everyone.

Comment: Joe, use more generic tags next time (like jQuery and Javascript) since people follow specific tags to find questions they can help with.

Comment: How do I close a request iWasRobbed

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Joe.  Close what request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reinventing the wheel: jQuery has built-in JSONP support, so you don't need to faff about implementing it yourself. Use the `$.ajax` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=ISBN' + isbnCode,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);  // log the response object to the console
    }
});
```

That should be all you need to do.

Comment: @lonesomeday: There is also the `getJSON` method which can be more convenient. It uses `ajax`. Just be sure to include `callback=?` in the URL. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp

Comment: @Gruber Yes, that's an option. Personally, I prefer being explicit in my code rather than relying on behind the scenes magic, so I prefer specifying `jsonp` rather than `callback=?`, which is far less clear on first reading.